# How to print all elements after a specific element in a list?

Tags: python, list

I want my output like if I choose the element 5 (not the index), only `4,7,6` will be printed.

```
b = [1,3,2,5,4,7,6]
Node = 5
for i in b:
    if Node == b[i-1]:
        continue;
    print(b[i-1])
```

Comment: `print(b[b.index(Node) + 1:])`

Comment: `i` is not an index of `b`. It's an element of `b`. You must change the loop to: `for i in range(len(b)):`

Comment: find position of array with `node = b.index(5)` and then `print(b[node+1:])`

Comment: What should happen if `Node` exists a few times in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    b = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
    node = 5
    for i in range(-1, -len(b), -1):
        if b[i] == node:
            for j in b[i+1:]:
                print(j)
            return 0
    for i in b:
        print(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What's the benefit of looping from the end?

Comment: In case b containes the value of node multiple times, the value of node closest to the end is used to decide from where values should be printed.

Comment: How do you know? It is not mentioned in the question... What if should be printed from the first one?

Comment: I think that is a fair point.

Comment: I think you got to explain your answer

Comment: Anyway I know you don't have enough rep to comment, but I already left one asking for clarification from the OP. We'll see if they give it...

Answer (score 0):

```
b = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
Node = 5
print(b[b.index(Node)+1::])  # [4, 7, 6]
```

Comment: Last colon is not needed

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `index` method and then use the found index to slice the list:

```
b = [1,3,2,5,4,7,6]
Node = 5
index = b.index(Node)
for i in b[index+1:]:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `print(*b[index+1:], sep="\n")`

Answer (score 0):

```
b = [1,3,2,5,4,7,6]
Node=5
index=b.index(Node)# fetching index of node
for i in b[index+1::]: #iterating through list after the node
     print(i)
```

Comment: Please Explain a bit more your answer

Comment: @TourEiffel In my script, we are slicing the list. But as per the problem statement, we have to slice it from the node. `index=b.index(Node)`  This code gets us the index of the Node (here it is 3) and then we use this index to slice the list into **[4,7,6]** using script `b[index+1::]`.Then we use For loop on the list [4,7,6]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid slicing and creating new lists, you can create an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) over the list and consume it until you reach the element, then print what is left:

```py
l = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
node = 5

it = iter(l)
for num in it:
    if num == node:
        break

for num in it:
    print(num)
```

Or use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to avoid the first loop:

```py
import itertools

l = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
node = 5

it = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x != node, l)
next(it)
for num in it:
    print(num)
```

Comment: `while next(it) <> node` looks better, imho

Comment: @OlvinRoght it might look better, but is it Python?

Comment: Do you mean `!=`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry, kinda tired :D

Comment: `next(it)` will raise an exception if the value isn't in the list. That may not matter for the OP, but I wonder if using `for num  in islice(it, 1, None)` without calling `next(it)`  might be a more flexible choice.