# Removing all strings from list before specific occurring string

Tags: python, string, split, integer

I have a list:

```
L1 = [5, -34, 0, 98, -11, 244, 193, 98, -10, -20, 45, 67]
```

the program requires a user to input a number--let's say 98 which is represented as 'n', and then I need to write a line of code that will print all elements of L1 after first occurrence of 'n', ie [-11, 244, 193, 98, -10, -20, 45, 67].
this is what I have so far, but I am very beginner so I am not sure where to go or how to change it.

```
if n in L1:
    L1.clear(n)
    print(L1)
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: `clear()` removes everything from a list, so you probably don't want that.

Comment: Or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69883930/how-to-print-all-elements-after-a-specific-element-in-a-list

Comment: `print(L1[L1.index(n)+1:])`

Comment: that's the thing. i dont know how to do it. i need to print the list with everything removed before the occurrence of 'n'

Answer (score 0):

For a very basic/brute force approach, you could just find the index of the value 'n' and print off the values after that index.

```
n = input()
n_index = L1.index(n)
print(L1[n_index+1:])
```

You could also loop over the list and have some sort of flag to trigger when you find that value:

```
n = input()
foundN = False
for num in L1:
    if foundN:
        print(num)
    if num == n:
        foundN = True
```

Comment: If you have to actually remove the values vs print them, that'll be a little different!

Comment: You're right @Mark. Edited!